# Divide by 0 warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have been working on an application and because images were acting up weird I decided to switch the Wall flag on to see if anything odd was going on. It revealed a new warning:

```
character.cpp(364): warning C4723: potential divide by 0
```

The odd thing is that there is no division going on anywhere around that point:

```
//Currently hp is always equal to 30
for (int i = 0; i < hp; i++) {
    int startXPos = i*12 + 40;
    if (i == hp-1) {
        gfx.DrawLine(10+startXPos,15,10+startXPos,40,245,245,245); //This line
        //This function expects: int, int, int, int, int, int, int
    }
}
```

Now this warning only occurs when I compile with the `/Ox` - flag (Full Optimization). When compiling with `/Od` (No Optimization) I do not receive the warning.

My question is: should I just ignore this warning (suppress it perhaps)? Or should I be worried? And what causes this?

Update:

Part of the DrawLine function:

```
int dx = x2 - x1;
int dy = y2 - y1;

if( dy == 0 && dx == 0 ) {
    //1 pixel line
}
else if( std::abs( dy ) > std::abs( dx ) ) {
    if( dy < 0 ) {
        std::swap(x1,x2);
        std::swap(y1,y2);
    }
    float m = static_cast<float>(dx / dy);
    //No different/more division past this point
```

Comment: what is `gfx.DrawLine`? Is that one of your functions?

Comment: @chuex Yes that would be the graphics object calling the DrawLine function.

Comment: just a wild guess, but maybe there is some inlining going on? Does `gfx.DrawLine` have any division inside of it?

Comment: I am seriously hoping that this code is just an excerpt and not existing as is in your project.

Comment: The difference between `/Ox` and `/Od` might be inlining, which is why this warning appears here. Hard to tell though without seeing more of your code base.

Comment: @Till Are you having problem with magic numbers? I mean, they're *magic*, come on, magic is awesome innit? ;)

Comment: Seeing your update: if the condition `dy == 0 && dx == 0` is false because `dx != 0` (but `dy == 0`) then you might enter the `else` branch and end up dividing `dx` by a zero `dy`. Fix your logic. Unfortunately you didn't show enough for us to be able to advise you in *how to fix it* so that's about it: just fix it.

Comment: @syam Seems you're right, should've looked at the algorithm aswell. Magic numbers are great when making initial 6 line functions though :P

Comment: @FlorisVelleman Magic numbers *seem* great. Until they bite you back. And the next time they still *seem* great. And they bite you back again. Again and again until you get tired of it and decide to start using named constants... We all went through that, we all got bitten by it, we all avoid it like the plague now... ;) When you catch yourself typing a magic number, even for a temporary implementation, always ask yourself "*can I give it a meaningful name?*". Even if it just ends up as a `const` variable in the same scope (in which case it will be optimized out by the compiler).

Comment: Just thought about it (the "fix your logic" part): perhaps you meant `||` instead of `&&` in your `dy == 0 && dx == 0` condition. Would be consistent with the "*1 pixel line*" comment. Can't guarantee it though since you showed us very little code, but from where I'm standing it looks logical (assuming there are other `else` clauses you didn't show us).

Comment: @syam the else contains pretty much the same as this else if statement (but then for dx). I changed < 0 to <= 0, in the if statements, which resolved the warning. I think || would make a vertical/horizontal line impossible with the current implementation.

Comment: Well the `&&` requires **both** deltas to be 0, so it simply can't be a line, it has to be a single point. `||` would require *either* delta to be 0 so you could have lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning happens because you have a possibility of "dy" being zero:

```
int dy = y2 - y1;
```

And 'dy' is used in a divide:

```
float m = static_cast<float>(dx / dy);
```

If 'y2' and 'y1' have the same value, then its the same as doing this:

```
float m = static_cast<float>(dx / 0);
```

Hard to know how to fix properly because we do not have the full algorith, but as a minimum: check dy before using it as a divisor. e.g (quick n dirty example):

```
float m = static_cast<float>(dy ? dx/dy : 0);     // 0 depends on your algorithm...
```

Or you may clip the line all together, interpreting y1 & y2 being equal to an infinitely small line which should not be drawn at all, in which case you would exit the DrawLine function immediately if dx or dy is equal to 0.

Answer (score -2):

Division by zero should be avoided. If you have the warning you should use some guard and handle this particular case (throwing an exception, handle it as special case in your codeflow ecc).